# How to select child rows joining two tables

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6

I have two tables:

1- Screen (ID,IsCheck,ParentID,IsActive)

2- RoleScreen (ID,RoleID,ScreenID)

Now I have a integer list of RoleIDs. I want to select all screens that exist in list RoleIDs as well as all the child screen where IsCheck is false.
Child Screen IDs does not exist within RoleScreen table.

I tried following code but it does not return child screen with IsCheck = false:

```
  this.context.Screens.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true) && 
                                  (
                                    (x.RoleScreens.Any(y => listUserRoleIDs.Any(z => z == y.RoleID))) ||
                                    (x.RoleScreens.Any(y => x.IsCheck== false && y.ScreenID == x.ParentID && listUserRoleIDs.Any(z => z == y.RoleID)))
                                  )).ToList();
```

Please guide me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: pardon me, to clarify, the child screen that you mention of is the one that have `ParentID` related to the given `RoleScreen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following models

```
  public class Screen
  {
      public Guid ID { get; set; }
      public bool IsCheck { get; set; }
      public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
      public bool IsActive { get; set; }
      public Screen Parent { get; set; }
      public ICollection<Screen> Children { get; set; }
      public RoleScreen RoleScreen { get; set; }
  }

  public class RoleScreen
  {
      public Guid ID { get; set; }
      public Guid RoleID { get; set; }
      public Guid ScreenID { get; set; }
      public Screen Screen { get; set; }
  }
```

And you want to retrieve:

- All Screens that belong to the given list of role ids
- All Child Screens for the given screens where its `IsCheck` is `false`
- All Child Screens that does not belong to `RoleScreens` table

In short, it retrieves any screen that designated in the list of role ids and its Child Screens.
This question however, may end up with Child Screens of the Child Screens that have its parent within the list (recursion problem).
However, if you are satisfied with only the immediate children, this query will satisfy your need:

```
  this.context.Screens.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true) && 
                                  (
                                    //Retrieve all Screen designated in RoleScreen
                                    (x.RoleScreens.Any(y => listUserRoleIDs.Any(z => z == y.RoleID))) ||
                                      //Retrieve all Child Screens
                                      ((x.Parent != null)
                                                         //Retrieve all Child Screens that don't have role assignment
                                                         && ((x.RoleScreen == null) || 
                                                         // Retrieve immediate children of the Screen designated in RoleScreen
                                                         // this part will need to be recursed somehow that is difficult if not utterly costly or impossible in classic linq
                                                         ((x.Parent.RoleScreens.Any(y => listUserRoleIDs.Any(z => z == y.RoleID)))
                                                           && (x.IsCheck == false))))
                                  )).ToList();
```

Disclaimer: I have not actually tested the query. Take it with grain and a lot of salt.
I hope someone can come up with better query.

Answer (score 0):

the Problem is here

```
(x.RoleScreens.Any(y => x.IsCheck== false && y.ScreenID == x.ParentID && listUserRoleIDs.Any(z => z == y.RoleID)))
```

I’m not entirely sure what you want, but if you want it how you wrote it and want ANY child then it should be:

```
(x.RoleScreens.Any(y => x.IsCheck== false && y.ScreenID == x.ParentID))
```

since the listUserRoleIDs.Any(z => z == y.RoleID) filters out all children who don't have the RoleID themselves.

---

on the other hand, if you want all the children of the screens which have a role then it would probably better to split it in two:

```
var Parents = this.context.Screens.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true) && 
                                    (x.RoleScreens.Any(y => listUserRoleIDs.Any(z => z == y.RoleID))));

var Children = this.context.Screens.Where(x => (x.IsActive == true) && (x.IsCheck== false) && (Parents.Any(y => x.ParentID == y.ScreenID)));

var List = Parents.Union(Children).ToList();
```